# Magento 2 Admin Login Error

Tags: magento-2.1.8

I am receiving this error, when i try to login through ADMIN.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `admin_user_session` (`session_id`, `user_id`, `status`, `ip`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

But, once i go back to PHPMYADMIN and EMPTY the MYSQL TABLE - admin_user_session, it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the `ID` field in the `admin_user_session` table have AUTO_INCREMENT? If it's not, please set the AUTO_INCREMENT for that table. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The EXTRA field is empty and when i click on edit structure and try to edit, that field is not displayed for editing.

Comment: Do you use phpAdmin?